# java(kotlin)でサブクラスから必ずsuperを呼ばせる

Tags: java, kotlin

java(kotlin)でサブクラスから必ずsuperを呼ばせることはできますか？
IDE保管（ビルドエラー)でもthrowでも良いのですが必ず呼ばせるようにしたいです。

Androidの開発で継承元fragmentのonSaveInstanceStateを利用しており、サブクラスからonSaveInstanceStateのsuperを呼ばれないとうまく動作しません。
可能であればビルドエラーをはくようにしたいです。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android限定で使ったことはないですが、`support-annotations` の`@CallSuper`アノテーションを使えば、コンパイル時にチェックを追加でるそうです。
詳しくは[アノテーションによるコード検査の改善](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/annotations)を。

Comment: @CallSuperなるものがあるのですね、とても助かりました！